# How to I use Vim's increment (Control-a) when in a screen session?

Tags: gnu-screen, vim, vimrc

Is there a way to re-map Control-a in screen to Alt-a or something else, so I can use Control-A in Vim normally (increments the number under the cursor)?

Comment: For a similar question, see http://superuser.com/questions/142680/bash-vs-gnu-screen-replace-ctrl-a-with-ctrl-shift-a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man screen`:

> -e xy
>               specifies the command character to be x and the character generating a literal command character to y (when typed after the command
>               character).  The default is "C-a" and `a', which can be  specified
>               as  "-e^Aa".  When creating a screen session, this option sets the
>               default command character. In a multiuser session all users  added
>               will  start off with this command character. But when attaching to
>               an already running session, this option changes only  the  command
>               character  of  the  attaching  user.  This option is equivalent to
>               either the commands "defescape" or "escape" respectively.
>
> defescape xy
>          Set the default command characters. This is equivalent to the  "escape"
>          except  that  it is useful multiuser sessions only. In a multiuser session "escape" changes the command character of the calling user,  where
>          "defescape"  changes the default command characters for users that will
>          be added later.
>
> escape xy
>          Set  the  command character to x and the character generating a literal
>          command character (by triggering the "meta" command) to y  (similar  to
>          the  -e  option).   Each  argument is either a single character, a two-character sequence of the form "^x" (meaning "C-x"), a  backslash  followed  by an octal number (specifying the ASCII code of the character),
>          or a backslash followed by a second character, such as  "\^"  or  "\".
>          The default is "^Aa".

Comment: Thanks. Seriously don't know how I missed that. Or else way back when I first started using screen I just had no perceived use for modifying the command-character and forgot about it...

Answer (score 10):

When in screen, just do "C-a a" instead of just "C-a"

ie Hit "Control-a" then type "a" again. The number under the cursor will increment!

Answer (score 2):

Found a possible solution:

map something unrelated in Vim to  like so: `map <Leader>inc<CR> <C-a>`

This is not a perfect solution, or maybe not even the "right" solution, but it works for now.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was just symetrical to yours: I wanted to keep working the usual way with screen, using the usual Control-A, and also use the increment in vim.

I just added these two lines to my .vimrc file:

```
:nnoremap <A-a> <C-a>
:nnoremap <A-x> <C-x>
```

, so that I now use Alt-A and Alt-X in vim to increase and dicrease numbers.